# Install packages with `make install`

Tags: git, makefile, package, make-install

I've installed a package (vim) in my raspberry pi (debian 11) by cloning the GitHub repository and running the commands `make` and `make install` as it's explained here https://tecadmin.net/install-vim-linux/

What I typed:

```
sudo apt install git make ncurses-dev build-essential
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then I read this: https://www.vim.org/git.php and I noticed that **I only made the building part**.

I was just following the steps and all right, I've done it. But after that I removed the downloaded folder and I have some questions about how this process works:

1. I should have kept the installation folder?
2. How can I remove/update the installed program? (I looked it up and it seems `make uninstall` is the command, but I'm not sure)

Comment: `make unistall` will only work in the directory where you ran `make install` from. A better solution in many respects is to build a package from the Debian sources and install the resulting `deb` file like you would any other package.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to just use the vim version from your distro repo. As your first link describes, you should use `sudo apt install vim`.

If you *really* need to compile it from source, you should keep the source folder and use `git pull` in that folder to get the latests sources, then check out the desired branch and build it again.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Thanks.